# Web Api Attribute Routing does not map?

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I have the following api controller which has a couple of get actions. this is a mvc site which is set in a different process and set as a sub domain to another site. the third action is supposed to return a cv, and takes in an Integer id and an optional string for the Cv name. I have been unable to get it to work unfortunately.

```
    public class TempsController : BaseApiController
    {            

        [GET(""), HttpGet]
        public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Get([FromUri] SearchCriteriaModel criteria)
        {
            .....
        }

        [Route("{candidateId:int}/preview/{keywords?}")]
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<CandidatePreviewDto> Get(int candidateId, string keywords)
        {
            ...
        }

        [HttpGet]
        [Route("{candidateId:int}/cv/{name?}")]
        public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Get(string name, int candidateId)
        {
            .....
        }

    }
```

this is the generated url:

```
"https://temp-search.recruiter.workstation.local:443/recruiter/temp-search/api/temps/14348508/preview/project"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by doing the following:

```
        [Route("api/temps/{candidateId:int}/preview/{keywords?}")]
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<CandidatePreviewDto> Get(int candidateId,
                                                   string keywords = "")
        {
            CandidatePreviewDto preview = await candidateService.GetCandidatePreview(new CandidatePreviewQuery
                                                                                     {
                                                                                         CandidateId = candidateId,
                                                                                         Keywords = keywords
                                                                                     });
            return preview;
        }
```